# How to connect a Toolbar Button to a Slot of another Widget?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'am trying some tutorials with Glade and GTKmm. For now I have a Main Window with a Toolbar. This is my Main Menu. Every Toolbarbutton should trigger the "show" and "hide" option of a widget.
In this case I have a widget called Overview. So, how do I connect the Toolbarbutton signal to a function (Slot) of the overview widget?

[Here is a little bit of code I already have.](http://pastebin.com/gM18UfiY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just connect a signal:

```
tbtnOverview->signal_clicked().connect(wndOverview, &Overview::Method_To_Fire);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know where. If I put it into the constructor of the main window, it will not work because the object wndOverview does not exist yet.

Comment: Why can't you do it right after `guiOverview->get_widget_derived("wndOverview",wndOverview);`?